# URL encode/decode issue - Jenkins and reverse proxy with IIS(rewrite)

Tags: jenkins, iis, reverse-proxy

I have using reverse proxy(via ARR). I have following rule setup in web.config.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Reverse proxy for jenkins" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(http?)://" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://localhost:8080/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I get following error while browsing this url. http:// jenkins.mytest.com/user/dmn%5Cmda

```
HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found
URI:    /user/dmn/mda
STATUS: 404
MESSAGE:    Not Found
SERVLET:    Stapler
```

- dmn-domain
- mda-username

**whereAs without domain(and slash) in URL it works well.** As following

i.e http:// jenkins.mytest.com/user/mda

Comment: After you install ARR, do you double-click the Application Request Routing Cache module, and click server Proxy Settings on the right, and check Enable proxy. You wrote at the end: "whereAs without domain(and slash) in URL it works well." I don't understand what form of URL would work well? Can you list it? In addition, you can try to track errors using failed request tracing.

Comment: i mean, 
If i login with "dmn\mda" and then click on the username on right top of jenkins. I get the above mentioned error.
If i login with "mda" as username and click on the username on right top of jenkins. It works

Comment: I don't think that the URL format is correct, I have not seen that the domain is also included in the path structure part of the URL, and it is wrong to include "\" in the url, only the path can contain "\".

Answer (score 0):

I have the following configuration for IIS precisely and it has worked for me, let me know if it is useful to you.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules useOriginalURLEncoding="false">
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://mydomain.com:8088{UNENCODED_URL}" appendQueryString="false" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(http|ws)://" />
                    </conditions>
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_FORWARDED" value="for={REMOTE_ADDR};by={LOCAL_ADDR};host=&quot;{HTTP_HOST}&quot;;proto=&quot;http&quot;" />
                    </serverVariables>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Additionally as a guide: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/reverse-proxy-configuration-iis/

Comment: Unrecognized attribute 'useOriginalURLEncoding'-- THis is what i am getting using the above config. Tried with removing this attribute. Still didnt work